# Function doesn't make it to the second if block

Tags: javascript, readline

I want to read multiple lines from the stdin, unfortunately my code doesn't get past the first if block no matter which option I choose.

```
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});
function clientOpener(){
  rl.question("Choose a number:\n1)Start a bowling game\n2)Exit simulation\n", function (startGame) {
    const y = "1";
    const n = "2";
    if(y === startGame){
      (async () => {
        const playerCount = await rl.question("Ok how many players will there be (MAX: 8 players)\n");
        const parsedInput = parseInt(playerCount);
        if (parsedInput > 0 && parsedInput <= 8) {
            let listOfNames = [];
            for (let i=0; i<parsedInput; i++) {
                const name = await rl.question(`Enter name #${i}\n`);
                listOfNames.push(name);
                console.log(`Added ${name} to list of players\n`);
            }
            console.log(listOfNames);
        }
        rl.close();
      })();
    }
    else if(n === startGame){
      console.log("Ending interface");
      rl.close();
    }
    else {
      console.log("Please enter a valid option");
      clientOpener();
    }
  });
}
clientOpener();
```

Console output (same output happens for else if and else options) :

```
1)Start a bowling game
2)Exit simulation
1
*console unresponsive*
```

Comment: How do you know it entered the first if statement?

Comment: I don't think your callback ever gets called. According to [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#rlquestionquery-options), `rl.question` returns a Promise. You are actually using it like this inside the if statement, but not in the initial call in `clientOpener`. Why?

Comment: What does rl.question returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that are going wrong in your attempt. One thing that is
problematic is the fact that you are trying to use readlines `question` with await
for which you need the readline/promises package that comes built-in with NodeJS.
The code below uses the asynchronous version of readline and seems to be doing what
you intended.

```js
const process = require("process");
const readline = require("readline/promises");

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

async function clientOpener(){
  let startGame = await rl.question("Choose a number:\n1)Start a bowling game\n2)Exit simulation\n");
  const y = "1";
  const n = "2";
  if(y === startGame){
    let playerCount = await rl.question("Ok how many players will there be (MAX: 8 players)\n");
    const parsedInput = parseInt(playerCount);
    if (parsedInput > 0 && parsedInput <= 8) {
      let listOfNames = [];
      for (let i=0; i<parsedInput; i++) {
        let name = await rl.question(`Enter name #${i}\n`);
        listOfNames.push(name);
        console.log(`Added ${name} to list of players\n`);
      }
      console.log(listOfNames);
    }
    rl.close();
  }
  else if(n === startGame) {
    console.log("Ending interface");
    rl.close();
  } else {
    console.log("Please enter a valid option");
    clientOpener();
  }
}

clientOpener();
```

Comment: They do call the anonymous async function, though? It looks like `(async () => { ... })()`. +1 anyways since this is how they should be using rl.

Comment: @vera In the orignal post that was missing. But thanks for mentioning that I will adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: I probably shouldve added the require statemtents into the code but I do have it included already. Aside from that was the main issue that I wasnt using promises correctly? It seems like there are specific places where I should be using the await keyword.